# Was Jonathan Archer really going to be called "Jeffrey Archer"?

Tags: star-trek, behind-the-scenes, star-trek-enterprise

I've seen in quite a few places a claim that when Star Trek Enterprise was being written, the character of Captain Archer was going to have the first name Jeffrey, and it was only because a British person on the team said, "You can't call him that!" that it was changed. (For the benefit of non-UK readers, Jeffrey Archer is the name of a British peer who is a prolific author and crook.) Is this true, or is it an urban myth?

Comment: According to the Guardian newspaper, yes; https://www.theguardian.com/media/2001/jul/23/pressandpublishing.broadcasting

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time something like this had happened. Al Pacino's character in *Heat* was called Vincent Hanna, a name well known in the UK at the time as that of a respected political journalist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one seems to have the *slight* ring of truth about it. The character of the captain of the Enterprise was originally going to be "**Jackson** Archer" but was likely changed because the name was not sufficiently [either widespread *or* unique](http://howmanyofme.com/search/?given=Jackson&sur=Archer)

> An early casting call sheet acquired by TV Guide reveals that the
> fifth series in the Star Trek franchise will be a prequel about the
> infancy of the Federation that predates the time of Kirk and Spock by
> 100 years
>
> Trek's usual emphasis on ethnic and intergalactic diversity will be
> evident in the other characters, including **Capt. Jackson Archer**, a
> bold rule buster with a grudge against the Vulcans; Lt. Joe
> Mayweather, an African-American helmsman with more experience than his
> captain; Ensign Hoshi Sato, who can imitate alien sounds; Dr. Phlox,
> an exotic alien who specializes in New Age medicine; and Chief
> Engineer Charlie "Spike" Tucker, a Southern good old boy. Now that's
> the real McCoy.
>
> <sub><sup>[TrekToday - Brannon Braga Registers 'Enterprise' Domain](http://www.trektoday.com/news/190301_07.shtml)</sup></sub>

The article points out that these may simply be *net rumours*, but in hindsight, given the accuracy of the article, it's much more likely that they had the real casting sheet.

---

Some two months later, it was stated that the name had been changed from Jackson to ***Jeffrey***, a common enough name in the US, but one that would come up immediately on a [websearch for the UK politician](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jeffrey%20archer). It's not especially surprising that they changed it again.

> Industry trade magazine Broadcasting & Cable, which originally
> revealed the Enterprise name, reported that Bakula has been "cast as
> [the] Enterprise skipper," and said the actor was in final negotations
> with Paramount. The paper's sources said that executives at UPN have
> been wanting to announce the new series for months now, and that the
> actual announcement could be expected by the end of this week.
>
> This was confirmed by television executive subscription service TV
> Tracker, which updated its listing for Enterprise Tuesday. **The site
> said that Paramount was still in negotiations with Bakula for the
> role, which it was now referring to as Jeffrey Archer. The original
> casting sheet referred to the character as Jackson Archer, but it is
> of course possible that he underwent a slight name change.**
>
> <sub><sup>[TrekToday: Scott Bakula: Is He In Or Out?](http://www.trektoday.com/news/260401_06.shtml)</sup></sub>

Comment: That casting sheet is awesome! I'd watch that Enterprise.

Comment: I think they should have made a sterling effort to be bolder with their casting.

Comment: Hoshi's bio is kind of weird though. The Hoshi we ended up with was fine.